# Magit blame only last commit (or range of commits)

Tags: magit

Can I have magit-blame somehow only show the changes introduced with the last commit?

EDIT: *what have I attempted?*

I've looked at the docs of magit-blame and explored all flags in the magit-blame interface. Essentially I've inherited a repository and I want to see the changes introduced by a commit whilst being able to continue working on the code. That's why I would like to have magit-blame-addition overlays and not a simple diff.

Comment: What have you attempted? Also, a blame of last commit makes little sense unless it's a merge conflict.

Comment: Thanks, you are right that I should've been clearer. I've added more context to the question. I want blame addition overlays so that I can have the most recently added lines marked in the buffer while I work on the code. A simple magit-blame shows me too many commits that end up distracting me more than helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have magit-blame somehow only show the changes introduced with the last commit?

No.

But you can get something similar using the [`diff-hl`](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) package. `diff-hl-mode` shows an indicator in the fringe for uncommitted changes, `diff-hl-flydiff-mode` causes that information to be updated on the fly, and `diff-hl-amend-mode` causes the changes from `HEAD` to be shown as well.